# Validating Data Sets in sql

Tags: sql

I have two data sets having six columns:

1. Previous month data
2. Current month data (including previous month data with update changes)

How do I get the  under mentioned sub data sets?

a.  records fully matched based on all the six columns(previous month records having no change in current month data)

```
select * from a where (c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6) in (select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6 from b );
```

b.  records fully not  matched based on all the six columns (new records in current month data).

c.  records have changes in any one column with the changed column identifier.

d.  records have changes in any two column with the changed columns identifier.

e.  records have changes in any three column with the changed columns identifier.

f.  records have changes in any four column with the changed column identifier.

g.  records have changes in any five column  with the changed column identifier.

Comment: DO we get paid for doing your homework?  ;)

Comment: You do not have a primary key column among these?

Comment: Are you using Oracle DB? Because that syntax doesn't work on all RDBMS's.

Comment: currently i dont have primary key column.

Comment: yes i m using oracle db  with java front end

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! You question looks like you copy/pasted a school assignment. Please edit your question and add what you have tried, code snippets, and any errors you get.

Comment: hello fiskeben, no it is not a school assignment it is our old data sets which we are reconciling and generating primary key on each records to incorporate in db to automate such system with java front end

Comment: @Andreas: that is standard SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name There are a lot of "standard" SQL that is not supported by even the major RDBMS vendors, so the question of RDBMS vendor is very relevant. E.g. that particular construct is not supported by MS SQL Server.

Comment: @Andreas: but it's not specific to Oracle. And support for that is pretty wide spread: Postgres, DB2, SAP HANA, Vertica, MySQL, MariaDB, HSQLDB, H2 and even SQLite also support this. But you are right: knowing the DBMS being used is important.

Comment: All of you may kindly suggest sql or java code to get alteast new records in current month data (which will be totally different from previous month)

Comment: One way to get all records from `b` without matching record in `a`: `select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6 from b MINUS select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6 from a` (Oracle). `select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6 from b EXCEPT select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6 from a` (MS SQL Server, PostgreSQL, SQLite). Construct not supported by MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

psuedo coded as you're light on details.

```
Select case when a.c1 <> b.c1 then 1 else 0 end as c1
       case when a.c2 <> b.c2 then 1 else 0 end as c2
       ...
       case when a.c6 <> b.c6 then 1 else 0 end as c6
from a inner join b on a.recordid? = b.recordid?
```

I use recordID? as there needs to be something distinct in your table that relates the current month record to the past month

That gives you a c1 through c6 column that has 1 if it's changed, 0 if it hasn't.  turn it into a subquery

```
select recordid? from 
(Select recordid?,
       case when a.c1 <> b.c1 then 1 else 0 end as c1
       case when a.c2 <> b.c2 then 1 else 0 end as c2
       ...
       case when a.c6 <> b.c6 then 1 else 0 end as c6
from a inner join b on a.recordid? = b.recordid?) a
where c1+c2+c3+c4+c5+c6 = x
```

X aligns to whichever question you are asking and how many columns changed.  x = 0 is no change.

Add in from comments.
I really hope you don't have too many lines

```
select * from 
(Select a.*, case when a.c1 <> b.c1 then 1 else 0 end as c1,
       case when a.c2 <> b.c2 then 1 else 0 end as c2,
       ...
       case when a.c6 <> b.c6 then 1 else 0 end as c6
from a inner join b on 1=1) a
where c1+c2+c3+c4+c5+c6 = 0
```

We've basically removed the join criteria.  This is known as a cross join and will produce this months records * prev month record in results, and then filter them down.  c1+c2+c3+c4+c5+c6 = 0 is an exact match.  c1+c2+c3+c4+c5+c6 = 1 will find 5 of 6 the same.  and so on.

You don't want this model to go on for long...sooner you can get to some normalized data the better.

Comment: actually these records are from manual data entry system and 13 months old data now we are recording it in db by comparing current month data with previous month data.  At-least if we got the result set of those records which are new in current month data set, it will be very helpful for us to proceed that automation.

Comment: @AnwerHussain - that works.   Do you have a key that lets you know thats record ID 25 in prev month and record number 25 in this month and thats what we are comparing on?

Comment: @AnwerHussain - and my apologies on the homework statement...they way you've posted this seems like a student putting homework up.  Happens more frequently on stack than you would want to know.

Comment: it was your true opinion, and i respect it. i m new here i should polish my questioning skills.

Unfortunately we do not have key to identify record at position N.

This can be done by eliminating the records which are fully matched in both table remaining records are those records which have both new and changed records, now we have to implement such algorithm which will distribute the new records and the records have any kind of change.

Comment: can we get the records from table current which are totally unmatched from table previous on all the six column, that will be the new records in current table.

Comment: I just understood what you're asking and my answer isn't quite that.  What you want to do is a cross join...in my answer I have  "on a.recordid? = b.recordid?".  Since you have no recordID, you need to cross join the tables.  editting answer